# Insert Span Element In CKEDITOR Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, tags, typescript-typings

I want to insert a span element with random id in to CKEDITOR. I tried to add like this;

```
const viewFragment = activeEditor.editorInstance.data.processor.toView(<span id=1>name</span>);
const modelFragment = activeEditor.editorInstance.data.toModel(viewFragment );

activeEditor.editorInstance.model.insertContent(modelFragment,activeEditor.editorInstance.model.document.selection );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example, using `ngModel` binding.

html

```
<p>This ckeditor in angular 10 :)</p>
<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="name" [data]="data"></ckeditor>
<button (click)="insert()">insert html</button>
```

ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  editor = ClassicEditor;
  data: any = `<span>Hello, world!</span>`;

  insert() {
    this.name += '<span>Hello, world!</span>';
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-ckeditor-n2x2f7)

Comment: @SainulAbideen Its due to p tag, instead use `span` updated my answer!

Comment: Its woking.. :)